# Flash stage dimensions when exporting for iPhone AND iPad

Tags: iphone, flash, ipad, stage

In the Flash CS 5.5 AIR settings for iOS, in the General tab of a panel, there's a menu that lets you specify the target device:

- iPhone;
- iPad;
- (both) iPhone and iPad;

What happens if I specify the third?

That is: I can't understand **if I can use the default stage dimensions (iPhone dimensions)** or I must eventually create a stage (and assets) for iPad (and it will work for iPhone too).

Can't find any documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the best way to find out is to actually try it out!

Many apps that work on both iPad and iPhone use the default stage dimensions and just resize the whole thing 2x when on an iPad. Although I haven't tried it with an AIR app, I would say the same behavior should be expected.

Comment: So, the stage size is not that important?

Comment: Confirmed: stage size seems no matter.